# How to delete rows on table when date column is already past 2 days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `orders` where it has columns named `date_received` and `status`. The `date_received` column contains dates, and the `status` column has integers from 0-3;

Is it possible to delete rows wherein my only criterias is that it has already been past 2 days and the status column is still 0.

Kind of like something like this :

`DELETE * FROM orders WHERE (current_date - date_received = 2 days) AND status = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The correct statement would be:

```
DELETE o
FROM orders o
WHERE date_received <= date_sub(current_date, interval 2 day) and
      status = 0;
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM orders WHERE date_received <= date_sub(current_date, interval 2 day) AND ' at line 1